# Prolog variables don't unify as supposed to

Tags: prolog

I have written the following in Prolog to test if second array is like first except it has twice more values:

```
twice([],[]).
twice([X|T1], [X1, X2|T2]) :- X == X1, X == X2, twice(T1, T2).
```

When I write `twice([1,2],[1,1,2,2]).` I get `true`, but when I query: `twice([1,2], X).` I get `false` instead of `X = [1,1,2,2]`, what is the problem?

Comment: == dont unify variables with possible answer and only check if given instantiation works

Answer (score 2):

That is because [**`==/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3D)/2) is *not* supposed to unify. It tests if two terms are the same (for variables if these are the same variables). Unification is done through [**`=/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2) which:

> **Unify `Term1` with `Term2`**. `True` if the unification succeeds.

You thus can write `X = X1`, but this is not necessary. Using the same variable will unify the vales, so you can implement `twice/2` as:

```
twice([], []).
twice([X|T1], [X,X|T2]) :-
    twice(T1, T2).
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the predicate `==/2` to compare the two variables `X1` and `X2`.

Actually you can also shorten the program significantly

```
twice([],[]).
twice([X|T1], [X, X|T2]) :- twice(T1, T2).
```